# What does this mean in C# and how can I use it?

Tags: c#, c++, reverse-engineering

I've got the following code in C++ that I'm looking at in IDA Pro:

```
__int64 __fastcall sub_14023B480(__int64 a1)
{
  return *(_DWORD *)(a1 + 0x384) > 0 && !(*(_BYTE *)(a1 + 0xE8) & 8) && !(*(_DWORD *)(a1 + 0x290) & 0x800000);
}
```

`a1` is an entity.

`0x384` points to a health value.

`0xE8` and `0x290` points to some kind of flag, but how come I can't write a check like this in C#:

```
if(!(a1 + 0xE8) & 8)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Since in C# the `&` operator returns in int value.

Comment: `(… & 8) == 0`?

Comment: what type is `a1` in the C# version? Int64? append a type suffix to numeric literals to match with the rest of the expression. show full code, and what compiler error or runtime exception do you get? "...int value...": the binary operator & takes integral types, and long/ulong are such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, the ! operator cannot be applied to non-boolean types like this - a fact that is known to surprise both C and C++ programmers.

To fix your flag check, you would write

```
if (((a1 + 0xE8) & 8) == 0)
{
    //Do something
}
```

All the brackets are required because of operator precedence. Without the "middle" bracket, "8 == 0" would be evaluated before the & and result in another compiler error, "Operator & cannot be applied to int and bool".